# Trigger useEffect again after API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following useEffect hook which runs on the initial loading of the page

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const getLeads = () => axios.get("/api/leads");

  const setLeadState = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getLeads();
      res.data.map(lead => setLeads(prevState => [...prevState, lead]));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  setLeadState();
}, []);
```

and then I have the following function to add new data to the api. This function is called on a form submit.

```js
const addLead = async (firstName, lastName, email) => {
  try {
    const body = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email
    };
    const res = await axios.post("api/leads", body);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

How can I call my useEffect hook again after the addLead function was executed? I tried something like this

```js
const [test, setTest] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  const getLeads = () => axios.get("/api/leads");

  const setLeadState = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await getLeads();
      res.data.map(lead => setLeads(prevState => [...prevState, lead]));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
  setLeadState();
}, [test]);
```

And then changed "test" in the addLead function, however this leads to an infinite loop with the page not rendering at all.

Comment: You could just call the same function inside `addLead` after the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the function that fetches/sets the data outside of the effect and then call that function after `addLead`

```js
const getLeads = () => axios.get("/api/leads");

const setLeadState = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await getLeads();
    res.data.map(lead => setLeads(prevState => [...prevState, lead]));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

// Initial load
useEffect(() => {
  setLeadState();
}, []);

const addLead = async (firstName, lastName, email) => {
  try {
    const body = {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email
    };
    const res = await axios.post("api/leads", body);
    // Load again
    setLeadState();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```